# undefined method `action_mailer' with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.8

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The full error is:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:77:in `method_missing': undefined method `action_mailer' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000102f545f8> (NoMethodError)
```

I've searched several variations of this error and come up empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your `config/application.rb` have `require 'rails/all'` at the top, or are you only requiring specific pieces of Rails?

Comment: Also you may not have it in your gem library. Try adding `gem "actionmailer"` in your Gemfile.

Comment: @dmarkow, 'rails/all'. Thanks.

Comment: Is there more of a backtrace below the error that you get?

Comment: @dmarkow and @YetAnotherGeek, i uninstalled rails 3.0.8 files and then reinstalled rails 3.0.8 and that fixed the problem. Thanks for your help gents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i uninstalled rails 3.0.8 files and then reinstalled rails 3.0.8 and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're requiring only specific parts from rails in you `application.rb` (i.e., not using `require rails/all`). Try putting `require "rails/all"` in there.